# How to make a NodeJS + ExpressJS API bulletproof?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I just started to code my first API, I'm very excited about it and looking for some advice & feedback to make my code better and secure. I thought my code is perfect as long as I called my API for the second time. The second request got data from the previous request, that's why I set the variables to zero (`discountCheck = 0`) if the variable is undefined.

- Is it the best practice to clear data from the previous request?
- I'm using validator to check the inputs, should I use other tools too?
- I declared the variables outside of the function to make the accessible in the following functions. Is there a better way to achieve it? `var discountCheck, code, delay;`
- I hope one day hundreds of people will use this API, that's why I want to make sure I don't forward informations from one request to an other.

```js
var discountCheck, code, delay;
app.get('/out/:account', async function (req, res, next) {
    x = req.params.account;
    
    if (typeof req.query.delay !== 'undefined') {
        delay = parseInt(req.query.delay);
        console.log('delay: '+delay);
    } else {
        delay = 6;
    }
    
    if (typeof req.query.code !== 'undefined') {
        code = validator.escape(req.query.code);
        console.log('code: '+code);
    } else {
        code = 0;
    }
    
    if (typeof req.query.discount !== 'undefined') {
        let discountCode = validator.escape(req.query.discount);
        discountCheck = await discount.find({ discount: discountCode }).toArray();
        discountCheck = discountCheck.length;
    } else {
        discountCheck = 0;
    }
    
    if (delay > 5 && delay < 1440 && tools.isValid(x)) {
        let response = await firstFunction(x);
        res.send(response);
        
        next();
    } else {
        res.status(400).send('Invalid input');
    }
});
```

...after this snippet I have 3 more functions:

```js
async function firstFunction(x) {
    secondFunction();

    return data; // API response
}

async function secondFunction(x) {
    console.log('I did few calls here..');
    
    thirdFunction();
}

async function thirdFunction(x) {
    console.log('Done');

    // Should I close any process at this point?

}
```

I appreciate any comments about the coding style too, I would like to build this API the best possible way.

Comment: That's probably better suited at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is there no DB behind this API? Typically, variables like 'discountcheck' would usually come from the DB, so you have that data for each request and its unique to the request. Otherwise that variable is stored in memory as a global and as such will use whatever it was defined as.. Then again I could be reading it wrong but its not super clear without seeing the full code and how data is posted or sent over.

Comment: @proxim0 I'm using Mongodb. I send the data here: `res.send(response);` In the other functions I only do some work in the db.

Comment: Its still kind of hard to grasp the flow of what you are doing here, but knowing that you have the data stored in a DB, then then you should simply be able to query the DB to determine if they have things like a discount code etc. The mongo npm package should be promise based, so you will just query the DB based on the route THEN => move to process based on the response and return the value. You probably want to look into some Auth via JWT or other token to ensure only valid users have access to the API